# Why is "a" missing in "running like clockwork"

Tags: grammar

I would like to know why the idiom "running like  clockwork" is not written as "running like  a clockwork"? Is there some common rule that explains this?

I am asking this question since I am not sure that this word is a mass noun, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwork

Comment: Because _clockwork_ functions as a mass noun. It's much like _flowing like water_. So, it's _"running like **a** clock"_, but _"[running like clockwork](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22running+like+clockwork%22&sourceid=ie7&ie=&oe=&safe=active)"_, just like it's _"flowing like **a** river"_, but _"flowing like water"_. By the way, had you asked this at [ell.SE], I would have left this as an answer, but, here on ELU, I think it's only worthy of a comment.

Comment: You're misparsing the expression - *clockwork* here isn't a noun in the first place. It's adjectival, as in [a **clockwork** mechanism](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+clockwork+mechanism%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Or [running like **crazy**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22running+like+crazy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I disagree with that. ‘Clockwork’ in this phrase doesn’t ‘feel’ adjectival to me, it feels entirely nominal. The ‘like’ in ‘running like crazy’ is semantically different (meaning ‘as if’, rather than ‘in the manner of’), and I’d call ‘a clockwork mechanism’ adjunctive more than adjectival. ‘Running like clockwork’ is parallel to ‘running like water’ to me, not to ‘running like crazy’.

Comment: @Janus: Personally, outside the specific set phrase *like clockwork* I'm only accustomed to using the word adjectivally (a *clockwork timer*, as opposed to an *electronic timer*, for example). So rightly or wrongly, that's how I interpret the set phrase. Using *clockwork* as a "mass noun" to mean "mechanical clock mechanisms in general", or whatever, seems a bit Victorian to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have to agree with Fumble here: "clockwork" is an adjective that describes spring-and-gear technology based off of how clocks work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think of it as a noun in those cases too, being used as an adjunct (as in an egg timer), so that might explain it. Certainly in ‘as regular as clockwork’ an adjectival interpretation seems quite impossible to me. The only place I can think of where it ‘feels’ like an adjective to me is in the sense ‘dreary, repetitive’, as in ‘a clockwork existence’—and even there I'm not sure it doesn't feel just nominal as adjectival, too.

Comment: What is " **a** clockwork?" If it ever is anything, what has it to do with the sentence?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

'Clockwork' is a mass noun, like 'water'. A clock does not have 'a clockwork' is just has 'clockwork' (like a river has 'water' not 'a water').

Comment: Great examples! 8^)

Comment: Thank you! Indeed according to http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clockwork this is a mass noun. I wonder now if there  is a mistake on this wiki page: "A clockwork is the inner workings of ..." Why do they write "A clockwork..." ? :)

Comment: @Dmitri - I suppose in that cause the author could try to argue that they were referring to all the clockwork as a whole (much like The Pacific Ocean is "a water"). I'm not sure your typical English paper grader would agree though. :-)

Comment: But a clockwork is the clockwork within a clock, while two clocks have two clockworks. right?

Comment: Like "A Clockwork Orange"?  Heh.  In that case, clockwork is actually an adjective, so no comparison.  On the other hand "A clockwork is the mechanism behind the clock's face" is talking about a specific instance of a clockwork, not a genericized clockwork, and thus needs the indefinite article.

Comment: The usage in Wikipedia is unreferenced. And I don't see any discussion of it. That's not a good sign.

Comment: @npst Actually no. People don't say that two clocks have two clockworks. Two clocks would both have clockwork.

Answer (score 3):

Clockwork is a noun that doesn't have to be instantiated in order to be used.  Other examples of this include: "Slow as molasses", "Smooth as ice".