# Where is the term clockwork used?

Tags: word-usage

I was watching some cartoon show with a bunch of rugrats over the weekend and the term clockwork toy was used.  It seemed to be referencing a wind-up toy.

Is there any part of the English speaking world that uses clockwork more commonly than wind-up?  What is the normal term outside the US?

> Example:  I could walk into a toy store in my area and ask if they
>   have any wind-ups?  It might take the kid working there a few seconds
>   to process it but he would understand wind-up toy.
>
> If I walked into a store and asked if they had any clockworks, I am
>   positive they would take me to some clocks/alarm clocks.
>
> I want to know where the term clockworks is common enough to be used
>   without major context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "a" missing in "running like clockwork"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126304/why-is-a-missing-in-running-like-clockwork)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am specifically asking about the term clockwork in relation to toys and word usage.

Comment: I can see that. But if you're asking about the difference between (adjectival) *clockwork* and *wind-up* that's General Reference (in respect of, for example, "a toy" they're synonymous). The earlier question goes more deeply into what other contexts the word can be used in, and what "part of speech" it might be classed as.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can see them being synonyms and that being general reference.  But I can't remember hearing the term clockwork toy in my life so I would like to know where it is used or if it is still used.

Comment: If you search [*clockwork toy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind-up_toy) you get the answer. A drill down on the term [*clockwork motor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwork_motor) confirms it.

Comment: @bib - Is the term more British in usage?  In the cartoon they just referred to the toy as "a clockwork".  I would be thoroughly confused by that word without seeing a lot of context.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Apparently, ***clockwork toy*** is [2-3 times more common in the UK than the US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clockwork+toy%2Cclockwork+toys&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclockwork%20toy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclockwork%20toys%3B%2Cc0) (Americans tend to prefer ***wind-up***). But I really can't see how any native speaker would find anything unusual in the usage.

Answer (score 3):

Anything mechanical in nature, especially one that relies on a complex series of gears, can be referred to as a "clockwork."

In your particular case, I would think that "wind-up toy" and "clockwork toy" would be synonymous.  However, at least for an American English speaker, "clockwork toy" sounds a bit old-fashioned, whereas "wind-up toy" is more modern.

In extreme cases, I could see "mechanical toy" and "clockwork toy" being synonymous to a layperson, but clockwork toys would be a strict subset of mechanical toys.

Answer (score 2):

In Britain at least the term 'clockwork toy' would be more used and more understood than 'wind-up toy'.

However even in Britain it would not be referred to as "a clockwork", but "a clockwork toy".

Comment: I agree; personally, I would only use *wind-up toy* to mean something like a cotton reel with an elastic band.